# Meaning of alpha = C in SVM

Tags: svm, constraint

I have been studying SVM lately, following [Andrew Ng's CS229 lecture notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf). I can understand most of the notes. But for the case where the KKT condition is satisfied at `alpha = C`, I am not sure what that means.

I know that for `alpha = 0`, the KKT condition is satisfied with inequality constraint, namely, the point lies above the decision function `yi * (w' * xi + b) = 1`. And for `0 < alpha < C`, the KKT condition is satisfied with equality constraint, namely, the point is a support vector. Now as for the case where `alpha = C`, I wonder what does this mean, does it mean that the point violate the constraint and that the penalty is `C * slack_variable`?

Comment: Please use math typesetting. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -1):

$C$ is the maximum and $\alpha$ can be and indicates the Support Vector is inside the margin.